# oplog enable on standalone mongod not for replicaset

Tags: mongodb

I am running mongod as standalone server .now i want to enable oplog for it ,i want to know whether it is possible or not ?

I knew I can do this by creating single node ReplicaSet ,but I want to do this without replica set .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got a reply from the MongoDb Team, and it's working fine.

To enable `oplog` on a standalone server, start `mongo` with `master` options.

On command line start `mongod --master`.

For conf file append the following line:

```
master=true
```

More details [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12039).

Comment: what about mongo 3.x?

Comment: Same thing, but master-slave replication is deprecated on Mongo 3.2. I'd recommend starting with `--replSet rs` and then running `rs.initiate()` on the MongoDB shell.

Comment: This is not valid syntax for the current mongod.conf file.

Answer (score 7):

For mongo 2.6 or greater the /etc/mongod.conf now uses a yaml format.

To enable the oplog add something similar to the below, note the `replication:` line may already exist, be sure to use spaces.

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  oplogSizeMB: 100
```

Full documentation here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication-options

Comment: A single node replicaset seems too be unable to be restarted without it getting stuck in "RCOVERING" and never exiting it...