# Mongodb enable oplog not working

Tags: mongodb

I have a standalone instance of mongodb (on windows) and want to enable oplog without replicaset.

I found this SO post and set the --master option in my windows service path. But oplog is not created. Any advice?

> D:\MongoDB\2.6.5\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath=D:\MongoDB\2.6.5\data\db\ --logpath=D:\MongoDB\2.6.5\log\mongo.log --service **--master**

[oplog enable on standalone mongod not for replicaset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487002/oplog-enable-on-standalone-mongod-not-for-replicaset)

Comment: Are you sure the logpath exists?

Comment: Yes, mongodb starts properly, collections are working fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides starting it with --master and --logpath you also need to enable it manually by executing the following in mongo shell:

```
use local

rs.initiate( { _id : 'q', version : 1, members : [ {_id : 0, host : '127.0.0.1'} ] } )
```